# Proving a sequence with induction reasoning

Tags: induction, factorial

I have an assignment which I am quite stuck on. The question is the following:
function f: N to N is defined recursivly:

```
f(k+1)=(k+1)*f(k) for each k in N. f(0)=1.
```

That is the factorial function.

Now I have to prove by induction:

```
1* f (1) + 2 * f (2) + 3* f (3) +....+n * f (n) = f (n +1) -1
```

I have made two steps:
1. proved that the equation is true for n=1.
2. I assume that the equation is true for n.

Now I have to prove the equation for n+1.

Now the equation is:

```
 1* f (1) + 2 * f (2) + 3* f (3) +....+n * f (n) + (n+1)*f(n+1) = f (n +2) -1
```

I have used the induction assumption (number 2 in my steps) to place:

```
f (n +1)-1
```

insted of:

```
1* f (1) + 2 * f (2) + 3* f (3) +....+n * f (n)
```

So now I got:

```
f(n+1)-1 + (n+1)*f(n+1)=f(n+2)-1
```

With a common factor of f(n+1) I got:

```
f(n+1)(n+2)=f(n+2)
```

Now this is the last step I made.

My question:
Can I, from the first definition, say the this final equation is true?

I mean, this is the factorial definition.

I can't PROVE my final step. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand why to use $\;f\;$ if we already have a nice, well-known notation for the factorial.

So you have to prove

$$\sum_{k=1}^n kk!=(n+1)!-1$$

So the inductive step is

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}kk!=\sum_{k=1}^nkk!+(n+1)(n+1)!\stackrel{\text{ind. hypothesis}}=(n+1)!-1+(n+1)(n+1)!=$$

$$(n+1)!\left[1+n+1\right]-1=(n+1)!(n+2)-1=(n+2)!-1$$

and we're done.

Comment: the expression i have to prove in my assignment is the long equation, that's how i got to the short equation at the end. I can't use factoial, but prove by induction. However, thank you.

Comment: Well, instead of factorial use all along in the above $\;f(k+1)\;$ ...it is the same.